# How to make an efficient difference of sets function?

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

How to write a nice code that removes all elements from given set A, that occur also in set B?
I would like to use `DeleteCases[]` for this purpose, but have no good idea how to make it efficient.

```
SetDifference[A_,B_]:=DeleteCases[A, ??? ]
```

Or to find out if theres a ready to use function already, as in Lists as Sets there is nothing like that mentioned.

Comment: There is `Complement` but it could be not efficient enough if you know that, for example, `A` has no duplicates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an adequate function: `Complement`, e.g.:

```
Complement[{a, b, c, d, e}, {a, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {b, e}
> ```

It works also with more sets, lists or with any heads, e.g.:

```
Complement[{a, b, c, d, e}, {a}, {c, e}, {d}]
```

> ```
> {b}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Sort order**

It should be noted that `Complement` sorts its output:

```
la = {e, d, c, b, a};
lb = {a, b, c};

Complement[la, lb]
```

{d, e}

If we want to get the original sort order, we can use `DeleteElements` (new in 13.1)

```
DeleteElements[la, lb]
```

{e, d}

**2. Duplicates**

`Complement` deletes duplicates, `DeleteElements` doesn't

```
la = {e, e, d, d, c, b, a};
lb = {a, b, c};

Complement[la, lb]
```

{d, e}

```
DeleteElements[la, lb]
```

{e, e, d, d}

To delete duplicates when using `DeleteElements`:

```
DeleteDuplicates @ DeleteElements[la, lb]
```

{e, d}

Answer (score 1):

Using `DeleteCases` and `Union`:

```
SetDifference[sets__?VectorQ, 
   Optional[opts : Automatic | "SortAndDistinct", Automatic]] := 
  Module[
    {setarray, sdiff, sdiffsorted},
    setarray = {sets};
    sdiff = DeleteCases[First @ setarray,
            Apply[Alternatives, Union @@ Rest[setarray]]
        ];
    sdiffsorted = Union @ sdiff;
    Switch[
            opts, Automatic,
                sdiff, "SortAndDistinct",
                sdiffsorted
        ]
   ];

   l1 = {b, e, d, a, b, c, d}; l2 = {b, c}; l3 = {a, f};

   SetDifference[l1, l2, l3]

   (*{e, d, d}*)

   SetDifference[l1, l2, l3, "SortAndDistinct"]

   (*{d, e}*)

   SetDifference[{a, b, b, d, e}, {c}, {c, e}, {d}]

   (*{a, b, b}*)

   SetDifference[{a, b, b, d, e}, {c}, {c, e}, {d}, "SortAndDistinct"]

   (*{a, b}*)
```