# Delete duplicates from hierarchy of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Is it possible for *Mathematica* to compare a number of lists of different sizes, and delete duplicates in a hierarchical manner?

For example, given the following lists:

```
list1 = {2, 5, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18};
list2 = {5, 8, 11, 16, 19, 21};
list3 = {5, 8, 9, 11, 16, 19, 21, 23};
```

I would like to output:

```
list1 = {2, 5, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18}
list2 = {8, 16, 19, 21}
list3 = {9, 23}
```

where `list1` keeps all its original elements, `list2` keeps only elements belonging to `list2` and not `list1`, and `list3` keeps only those elements not contained in `lists 1 & 2`.

If this will take an inordinately long time, I am happy with just comparing the list with the previous list and deleting the duplicates from the second list.

Comment: Closely related [How to make an efficient difference of sets function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34270/how-to-make-an-efficient-difference-of-sets-function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be done with set operations:

```
list1
Complement[list2, list1]
Complement[list3, Union[list1, list2]]
```

Comment: @ Ubpdqn, thank you very much for your help on this :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Fold` to extend [ubpdqn's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1997) use of `Complement` and `Union`.  Pre-sorting the lists isn't necessary, especially if they are already sorted, but it ran slightly faster on large random lists.

```
list1 = {2, 5, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18};
list2 = {5, 8, 11, 16, 19, 21};
list3 = {5, 8, 9, 11, 16, 19, 21, 23};
lists = {list1, list2, list3};

Reap[Fold[(Sow @ Complement[#2, #1]; Union[##]) &, {}, Sort /@ lists]][[-1, -1]]

(* {{2, 5, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18},
    {8, 16, 19, 21},
    {9, 23}}                    *)
```

Comparison with and without `Sort`:

```
Block[{lists},
 SeedRandom[1]; 
 lists = Table[RandomInteger[2 * 10^5, RandomInteger[{10^3, 10^4}]], {200}]; 
 Reap[Fold[(Sow @ Complement[#2, #1]; Union[##]) &, {}, 
      Sort /@ lists]][[-1, -1]] // Last // AbsoluteTiming
 ]

(* {0.951474,
    {130, 8034, 9175, 19773, 23884, 25942, 32039, 35681, 43301,
     48881, 55009, 55076, 59170, 60909, 74140, 75298, 79379, 84588, 
     96241, 100238, 101899, 104788, 106787, 109378, 110730, 118780, 
     120469, 121675, 124215, 129721, 130787, 136182, 137604, 138686, 
     143374, 152045, 161277, 169106, 171461, 188972}}                *)

Block[{lists},
 SeedRandom[1]; 
 lists = Table[RandomInteger[2 10^5, RandomInteger[{10^3, 10^4}]], {200}]; 
 Reap[Fold[(Sow @ Complement[#2, #1]; Union[##]) &, {}, 
      lists]][[-1, -1]] // Last // AbsoluteTiming
 ]

(* {1.009209,
    {130, ..., 188972}}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [UniqueElements](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UniqueElements.html) (new in 13.1)

```
a = {2, 5, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18};
b = {5, 8, 11, 16, 19, 21};
c = {5, 8, 9, 11, 16, 19, 21, 23};

Last @* UniqueElements /@ {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}}
```

{{2, 5, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18}, {8, 16, 19, 21}, {9, 23}}